# Can we use gmail api to access outlook, yahoo mail etc?

Tags: gmail, email-client, gmail-api

Does gmail api allow us to access other email provider api or it is just limited on gmail ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's limited to Gmail and Google Apps accounts. To standardize across email providers, you should probably use a protocol like IMAP.